# REACT: Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: reactjs

I need to use a quantity for my cart, I'm learning react, but I get this warning: `Warning: Received NaN for the` children `attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.`

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext([]);

export const CartProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    //const cantidadProductos = cart.length;


    const [cartQuantity, setCartQuantity] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getQuantity = () => {
            let cantidadTotalProductos = 0;
            cart.forEach((orden)=>{
                cantidadTotalProductos += Number(orden.cantidadTotalProductos);
            });
            setCartQuantity(cantidadTotalProductos);
        }
        getQuantity();
    }, [cart]);



    const addItem = (item, cantidad) => {
        const newItem = { item, cantidad };
        const itemEsta = cart.find((order) => order.item.id === item.id);

        if(itemEsta){
            const actualizarCarrito = cart.map((order) => {
                if(order.item.id === item.id){
                    return {...order, cantidad: cantidad + order.cantidad};
                }else{
                    return order;
                }
            });
            setCart(actualizarCarrito);
        }else{
            setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, newItem]);
        }
    };

    const removeItem = (id) => {
        setCart((prev) => prev.filter((element) => element.item.id !== id));
    };

    const clearAll = () => {
        setCart([]);
    };


    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, addItem, removeItem, clearAll, cartQuantity }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useCart = () => useContext(CartContext);
```

And then in the component:

```
import './Carrito.css';
import { useCart } from "../context/CartContext";

function Carrito () {

    const { cartQuantity } = useCart();
    return <div className="editarCarrito">
        <p className="carritoCantidad">{ cartQuantity }</p>
    </div>
        
}

export default Carrito;
```

Comment: What does `useCart` do? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue? Have you checked, for example, that `orden.cantidadTotalProductos` _really is_ a number every time?

Comment: Please add information in the question rather than cramming it into comments.

Comment: `numberType += non-numberType` -> `NaN` You should ensure all your arithmetic operations maintain a number type invariant. I also just want to point out that cart totals are generally considered derived data from state, so they shouldn't also be part of state. Please update your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Its my first time here in stackover, sory if the answer is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The code is doing an arithmetic operation with a non-number type, and once this occurs the result is `Nan` and by definition any further arithmetic operations also always result in `NaN`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getQuantity = () => {
    let cantidadTotalProductos = 0;
    cart.forEach((orden)=>{
      cantidadTotalProductos += Number(orden.cantidadTotalProductos); // <-- cantidadTotalProductos is undefined
    });
    setCartQuantity(cantidadTotalProductos);
  }
  getQuantity();
}, [cart]);

const addItem = (item, cantidad) => {
  const newItem = { item, cantidad }; // <-- no cantidadTotalProductos property
  const itemEsta = cart.find((order) => order.item.id === item.id);

  if (itemEsta) {
    const actualizarCarrito = cart.map((order) => {
      if (order.item.id === item.id) {
        return { ...order, cantidad: cantidad + order.cantidad };
      } else {
        return order;
      }
    });
    setCart(actualizarCarrito);
  } else {
    setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, newItem]);
  }
};
```

## Solution

I think `cantidad` is the quantity value you are wanting to sum over. Provide a fallback value in case `Number(cantidad)` isn't a number.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const cantidadTotalProductos = cart.reduce(
    (total, { cantidad }) => total + (Number(cantidad) || 0),
    0
  );
  setCartQuantity(cantidadTotalProductos);
}, [cart]);
```

### Suggestion

The cart item total quantity is what is considered derived state since it's easily computable from the *actual* cart state, and really shouldn't also be stored in state. Compute it in the render result as part of the context value.

[Identify The Minimal (but complete) Representation of UI State](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state)

> Let’s go through each one and figure out which one is state. Ask three
> questions about each piece of data:
>
> 1. Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 2. Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 3. **Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn’t state.**

Example:

```
const cartQuantity = cart.reduce(
  (total, { cantidad }) => total + (Number(cantidad) || 0),
  0
);

return (
  <CartContext.Provider
    value={{ cart, addItem, removeItem, clearAll, cartQuantity }}
  >
    {children}
  </CartContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: Yeah! thank you so much! thats the solution.